# Lower-case roman numerals in enumerate with Spanish babel

Tags: numbering, lists, roman-numerals, spanish

I want to use lower-case roman numerals in a list, and I used:

```
%Redefine the first level
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\Roman{enumi})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi}

%Redefine the second level
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\roman{enumii})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}
```

But I get upper-case roman numerals for both the first and the second level (I actually get smaller roman numerals for the second level).

Is there a way to use lower-case roman numerals?

Here is an example of the code I used:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}

\newtheorem{mydef}{Definición}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lema}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposición}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corolario}
\newtheorem{remark}{Nota}

%opening
\title{Tarea I}
\author{Pedro
    \and Mateo}
\date{11 de Diciembre de 2013}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

%Redefine the first level
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\Roman{enumi})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi}

%Redefine the second level
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\roman{enumii})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Muestre que $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ no tiene automorfismos no triviales.
        \begin{proof}
            Dada la extensión de campos $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}$
        \end{proof}

    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

Comment: your code works fine here (I get lowercase roman numerals for the second level). Could you post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows the context where your code fails?

Comment: Ok, I've posted the entire code just to make sure is not the packages or something like that.

Comment: It seems to be a package issue. Comment out `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` and you will see.

Comment: if you want to keep babel replace `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` with `\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman]{babel}`. the option `es-lcroman` will do the trick.

Comment: @dcmst I invite you to post your comment as a possible answer.

Comment: Ok, using `\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman]{babel}` solved the issue, thank you.

Comment: Does anyone want to post the answer? or should I post it myself?

Comment: here it is, I was searching for references :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the author of the Spanish version of babel lower case roman numerals should not be used when writing in Spanish.

You can find more information about this issue in this [blog](http://www.tex-tipografia.com/spanish2.html) (in Spanish) and in the `babel-spanish` manual at page 4 (again, in Spanish).

Lower case roman numerals can be restored via the `es-lcroman` option, which is documented at the same page of the `babel-spanish` manual.

The result with `\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman]{babel}` in the preamble is the following:

[image]