# Page number problem with roman lower case

Tags: numbering, page-numbering

I have problems with pagenumbering, because I want the pages to be numbered with romans in lower case but at the moment of using \pagenumbering{roman} since at the time of compilation it is still showing the numbering with Romans in upper case.

I attach my latex code and I do not know which of the lines may be causing the aforementioned problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside,a4paper ]{book}
%\usepackage[Most]{romannum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}%centrar formulas
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsbsy}%Para poner fórmulas químicas
\usepackage{subfigure} % subfiguras
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{booktabs} %Para tablas importadas de excel
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}%row color
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float} %Para dejar fija la tabla 
%\usepackage{longtable} %Tabla en dos páginas
\usepackage{stackrel}
%\usepackage{enumerate} 
\usepackage{upgreek}%Para poner letras griegas en negrita
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{subfigure} % subfiguras%Para imágenes seguidas
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[myheadings]{fullpage}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig, setspace, booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{fourier}
%\usepackage[protrusion=true, expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{setspace} %interlineados
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{enumerate} % enumerados
\usepackage{emptypage}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{algorithm}%Escribir algoritmos
\usepackage{algorithmic}%Escribir algoritmos
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\fancyhf{} % <================ clears header and footer on all positions
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{} % clears header and footer on all positions
  \fancyfoot[C]{\bfseries \thepage} % <=================================
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancyhf{} % <==================================== allready done above!
\fancyfoot[C]{\bfseries \thepage}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}} 
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{Figura }
\renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{Tabla }
\author{Alex Pozo}
\parindent= 0mm %Elimina la sangria
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contenido}
\renewcommand{\partname}{Parte}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Apéndice}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{ÍNDICE GENERAL}
\renewcommand*\bibname{REFERENCIAS BIBLIOGRÁFICAS}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Anexos}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Anexos}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Anexos}
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % para que ponga subsubsecciones en el indice
\providecommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\providecommand{\norm}[1]{\lVert#1\rVert}
%------------------------------------------------

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\newtheorem{defi}{Definición}[chapter]
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposición}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lem}{{ Lema }}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}{{ Teorema }}[chapter]
\author{Alex Pozo}

\title{MODELIZACIÓN MATEMÁTICA DE TIEMPOS DE VIAJE DE LA TRONCAL CENTRAL TROLEBÚS.}
\setlength\parindent{2em }
\newcommand{\HRule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}
\onehalfspacing
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}

\begin{document}
\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{roman} %Here is my problem. Doesn't change the format
%CARÁTULA

%\pagestyle{empty}%Para eliminar encabezados y pies de pagina
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contenido}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Referencias Bibliográficas}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contenido}
%\newcommand{\defeq}{\mathrel{\mathop:}=}
%------------------------
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

Result of the compilation
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your MWE is incomplete as at least `\end{document}` is missing. However after adding this and some text, I could replicate that problem.

It seems to be that the book documentclass assumes that *large* roman numbers should be used for spanish texts. If you change the default language to (for example) english, you get small roman numbers instead.
There is a solution: load babel as `\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman]{babel}`
=> source for this: [the answer from Nico Boni](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148599)

Please note that the documentclass `book` provides two commands that you could use instead of `\cleardoublepage`\pagenumbering{...}`:

- `\frontmatter`
- `\mainmatter`

Both switch the pagenumbering and reset the page counter. See their documentation at [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/book?lang=de)

Comment: \usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman]{babel} was the solution. Thank you!